# Inbound calls from Russian phone numbers to Russian Toll-Free phone number

Tags: twilio

My project has an IVR system which I'd like to build with Twilio. The project is targeted to Russia, so I expect inbound calls to the IVR from Russian phone numbers. An IVR's phone number should be toll-free.

The Twilio Console's ["Buy a Number" section](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/search) doesn't offer Russia in the list of countries. Also, I talked to a Twilio representative by phone and he said currently I can't get a Russian Toll Free number from Twilio (for inbound calls).

My question is:
If I buy a Russian toll-free number from one of Russian providers, will I be able to bind it somehow to Twilio for incoming calls, so that Russian phone numbers can call it and use the Twilio IVR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can do this as Twilio provides SIP interfaces too. I am no expert in SIP though, so the best thing I can do is direct you to [this walkthrough that shows you all the steps you need to go through to connect an external number to Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/04/bring-your-own-numbers-with-twilio-sip-interfaces.html):

Comment: Thanks a lot, @philnash!